# Cannot figure out when to hide and show loading animation with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, animation, loading

I have a loading animation which I initially hide in my application.js file:

```
$('#loading_field').hide();
```

I have an autocomplete field, and I want the animation to appear when the user starts typing, and for it to disappear when the autocomplete suggestion results appear. Below is my jquery code for the jquery ui autocomplete plugin:

```
$(".showable_field").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: '/followers.json',
    focus: function(event, ui) {
       $('.showable_field').val(ui.item.user.name);
       return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var video_id = $('#video_id_field').val();
        var user_id = ui.item.user.id;
        $.post("/showable_videos.js", {video: video_id, user: user_id});
        $(':input','#new_showable_video').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('');
        return false;
    }
});
var obj = $(".showable_field").data('autocomplete');
obj && (obj._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
       .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
       .append( "<a>" + item.user.name + "</a>" )
       .appendTo( ul );
});
```

Where should I show and hide the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using AJAX to load the suggestions I think this should work for you:

```
$('#loading_field').ajaxStart(function () {
  $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: however this kind of falls apart if you have loading animations in different places...

Answer (score 4):

Well, jQuery UI automatically adds the class 'ui-autocomplete-loading' to your input when it is loading remote data, so the absolute easiest way to do this is to simply put an animated GIF in as the background image on your input when that class is present.

That's what they do in the [remote-loaded example on jQueryUI.com](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) (note that you have to type two more more characters to kick off the ajax call in this example).

```
<style>
  .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat; }
</style>
```

Comment: This is a great CSS way to do it as well.  Good answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yours seems useful if the OP really wants to manipulate some other element to show the animation; upvoted.